# Magento 2 : Add Custom Validation After Shipping Address Has Been Entered

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, shipping

When a customer enters their shipping address (in standard Magento 2 checkout process), I need to look at each of items in their shopping cart and call an External REST API to validate that item is not excluded from shipping to their state. If item is not valid in their state, then I need to redirect them back to their shopping cart and display a validation message explaining why they cannot place their order.

The external REST API is already built and works, but I have not been able to figure out where to inject this validation at. I want to do this by using an observer that observes when the user completes the first step of the checkout process (where they enter their shipping address information). What I need to  know is, is there an event triggered at that time and if so what event should I attache the observer too. Or is there another way of accomplishing the same objective?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!